# mporthow to read and write into text file

Tags: c++

i have created a program for a students data base in c++. The data base has 7 options to select from. such as enter students details, edit record, etc. the different options are select-able through case statements. My issue is with case 6. Where by i have to display the entered text into a text file and be able to read and write to/from it. I can write to it but not read to it.I just posted the case 6 section. 
Note: I created a class to store students information such as name,surname etc, and "stud" is an object of class students.

```
    class students
    {
        public:

        char name[50];
        char sname[45];

        int idno;
        char cours[40];
        int age;
        int modules;

        void read_data();
        void display();

    }s;

   void students::read_data()
   {
        cout<<"Enter name :";
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"Enter Surname : ";
        cin>>sname;
        cout<<"Enter course : ";
        cin>>cours;
        cout<<"Enter age :";
        cin>>age;
        cout<<"Enter modules:";
        cin>>modules;
      }
    void students::display()
    {
        cout<<"-----------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"Student ID no : "<<idno<<endl;
        cout<<"Student name is :"<<name<<endl;
        cout<<"Student Surname is : "<<sname<<endl;
        cout<<"Student course is :"<<cours<<endl;
        cout<<"Student age is  :"<<age<<endl;
        cout<<"Student modules are:"<<modules<<endl;
        cout<<"----------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    }

     int main()
     {

       char dow;
       int arr=0;
      do{

        students stud[100];

        cout<<"Press 1 Enter record \n";
        cout<<"Press 2 Display record \n";
        cout<<"\n\t Select option::";

        int idcheck=0;

        int sw;
        cin>>sw;

        switch(sw)
        {

        case 1:

        cout<<"\n Enter the data of the student no "<<arr+1<<" is :\n";

                cout<<"\t Enter the Roll No = ";
                int id2;
                int id;

                cin>>id;

                for(int j=0; j<arr; j++)
                {

                    id2=id;
                    if(id2==stud[j].idno)
                    {
                        idcheck=1;
                     }
                 }
                 if(idcheck!=1){
                    stud[arr].idno=id;

                 stud[arr].read_data();

                    arr=arr+1;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    cout<<"This Record is Already Entered \n"; 
                 }

                 break;
    case:2   
   {
    ifstream sfile;
    sfile.open("StudentFile.txt", ios::in);

    cout << "\n-----------------------------------------------" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
    cout << setw(12) << "Rollno ||";
    cout << setw(12) << " Name   ||";
    cout << setw(12) << " Surname    || ";
    cout << setw(12) << "Age  ||";
    cout << setw(12) << " Course  ||";
    cout << setw(12) << " Module   ||";

    for(int k = 0; k < arr; k++)
    {
        if(stud[k].idno != 'd')
    {
            cout << "\n";
            cout << " ";
            cout << setw(5) << stud[k].idno;                            
            cout << setw(15) << stud[k].name;                           
            cout << setw(14) << stud[k].sname;                       
            cout << setw(14) << stud[k].age;                         
            cout << setw(12) << stud[k].cours;                       
            cout << setw(14) << stud[k].modules;                        
    }
    }
    }
     cout << "\n-------------------------------------------"   << endl;

     sfile.read((char*)&s, sizeof(s));
     sfile.close();
}
```

Comment: I'd love to help, but I think my eyeballs just burst in horror.

Comment: First, take the time to properly edit your question. Second, none of the code that actually opens the file is shown. How are we supposed to help if you don't even show the relevant code?

Comment: i noticed i didn't fully post the  code.i edited it already

Comment: Copy and paste the code. Select it and use the {} button in the editor to form a code block.

Comment: just did thank thanks @drescherjm

Comment: how did you do that @ChrisMM, sort it that way

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into an IDE which auto formatted, and pasted it back. That's all.  Also, there's definitely important code missing from your snippet, like what is `stud`. Also, what exactly is the issue you are having? Oh, and you're missing a semi-colon in the example, first line.

Comment: i just added the semi colon. the stud is an object of a class called student. well i cant read from the file i created

Comment: What do you mean with **"nothing happens"**? What is nothing and how do you know it happens? Or even better, what _should_ happen and what _acutally_ happens?

Comment: well when i say nothing happens i believe the code for reading the program does not work well. It is supposed to read from the text file, not just write to it.  @churill

Comment: But how do you know? You got one line that reads from the file `cfile.read( (char *)&stud, sizeof( stud ) );` Does it crash or do you get wrong results or does your program never finish?

Comment: i get the wrong results meaning it does not read at all

Answer (score 0):

A stream contains two "pointers" that point to the position where it is reading and where it is writing. If you are writing, then the read pointer is also advanced. So
you first want to move the read pointer backwards the amount of bytes you are going to read with [seekg()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg):

`cfile.seekg(-static_cast<long>(sizeof stud), cfile.cur);`

## MRE / proof of concept

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

struct Foo {
    int i = 2;
    double d = 3.13421;
    float f = 3241.41f;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const Foo& foo) {
    return s << "i=" << foo.i << "; d=" << foo.d << "; f=" << foo.f;
}

int main() {
    std::fstream file;
    Foo foo;

    file.open("foo.txt", file.in | file.out | file.trunc);

    file << "some other text";

    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&foo), sizeof foo);

    std::cout << foo << std::endl;

    foo.i = foo.d = foo.f = 0;

    file.seekg(-static_cast<long>(sizeof foo), file.cur);

    std::cout << foo << std::endl;

    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&foo), sizeof foo);

    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
}
```

produces the following output:

```
i=2; d=3.13421; f=3241.41
i=0; d=0; f=0
i=2; d=3.13421; f=3241.41
```

Comment: oh so i put that right above   that code:   cfile.read( (char *)&stud, sizeof( stud ) );

Comment: Meaning? You need be a bit more specific about _what_ is not working.

Comment: i tried to use the code you provided cfile.seekg(-static_cast<long>(sizeof stud), cfile.cur); . It still does not read the data in the file. and when in the text file it now shows different characters.

Comment: Are you sure? How do you check if it reads the correct data?
I will attach a MRE to my answer.

Comment: well i created a case statement and the code i posted as my question is case number 6. so when i check if it reads the correct answer i re-run the program to check if the data i previously entered is still available. If it is not it means the code didn't work for reading the data.

Comment: Then you are reading it wrong somewhere else. Either add the relevant code to your question or ask a new question

Comment: i just edited the question maybe you'll understand better. that is the relevant code. i can't add the whole program

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Is your problem that you do `cfile.write( (char *)&stud, sizeof( stud ) ); cfile.read( (char *)&stud, sizeof( stud ) );` and then `stud` has the wrong value? (Where you refuse to show the code where you check this value)
If you say you _rerun the whole program_ and then get to the wrong case it means that this is _not_ the relevant code. Also _the code didn't work for reading the data_ You only got one line where you read something inside the code you posted....

Comment: well my problem is i can write to the cfile, but i can not read to the cfile.

Comment: Ok, simple question: As I understood it: you call `cfile.write( (char *)&stud, sizeof( stud ) );` then `cfile.read( (char *)&stud, sizeof( stud ) );` and then stud contains the wrong data. Is this right?

Comment: the calling part if true, but stud containing the wrong data is wrong. stud contains the right data.

Comment: Then I'm even more puuzled as to what is your actual problem :D

Comment: i can not manage to read from the text file. that is the problem

Comment: But you _do_ read from it with `cfile.read( (char *)&stud, sizeof( stud ) );`.

Comment: when i run the program it is completely empty. Yet i entered data before i exited the program.

Comment: It could be that you accidentally overwrite the file somewhere....In the code you show there is only one line where you read something. And that is _after_ writing the file. So obviously the problem is somewhere else. Best you open a new question.

Comment: i provided a minimal reproducible example, by editing the code i wrote as a question. It is much clear now.

Comment: In the last revision of your code you were writing to _but only once reading from_ "CourseFile.txt". Now you show code, where you read from _but never write to_ "StudentFile.txt". Maybe that's the error that the filenames don't match??? I think it would be easier if you learn how to debug a program yourself.